# Neo4j tests and lock file issue

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot

My application is written with Neo4j and Spring/Spring Boot/REST Spring MVC.
I have a bunch of unit/integration tests. Everything work properly when I'm using for tests Neo4j Server via REST but when I'm using Embedded Neo4j I continuously get following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't lock lock file test-db\lock because another process already holds the lock.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getLockFileBasedFileLock(FileLock.java:120)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getOsSpecificFileLock(FileLock.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.tryLock(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:93)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)
    ... 167 common frames omitted
```

The second test is always fails.. Obviously, some resources(Neo4j, web application) are not correctly released between tests invocation. Right now I have no idea how to correctly release resources..

This is my Neo4Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example")
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private static final String NEO4J_EMBEDDED_DATABASE_PATH_PROPERTY = "neo4j.embedded.database.path";
    private static final String NEO4J_SERVER_DATABASE_URI_PROPERTY = "neo4j.server.database.uri";

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    public Neo4jConfig() {
        setBasePackage("com.example");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(environment.getProperty(NEO4J_EMBEDDED_DATABASE_PATH_PROPERTY));
        // return new SpringRestGraphDatabase(environment.getProperty(NEO4J_SERVER_DATABASE_URI_PROPERTY));
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    public BeanFactory getBeanFactory() {
        return beanFactory;
    }

}
```

This is my Application main class:

```
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties") })    
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And for example, one of my tests

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@IntegrationTest("server.port: 0")
public class UsersControllerTest {

    private final static String USERNAME = "username";
    private final static String PASSWORD = "password";
    private final static String EMAIL = "test@test.com";

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    protected int port;

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler());
        restTemplate.delete(format("http://localhost:%d/users/delete", port));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler());
        restTemplate.delete(format("http://localhost:%d/users/delete", port));      
    }

    @Test
    public void createUser() {
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ResponseErrorHandler() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                return RestUtils.isError(response.getStatusCode());
            }

            @Override
            public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, response.getStatusCode());
            }

        });

        User user = new User(USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL);

        Assert.assertNull(user.getId());
        Assert.assertNull(user.getCreateDate());

        User registeredUser = restTemplate.postForObject(format("http://localhost:%d/users/create", port), user, User.class);

        Assert.assertNotNull(registeredUser);
        Assert.assertNotNull(registeredUser.getId());
        Assert.assertNotNull(registeredUser.getCreateDate());

        restTemplate.postForObject(format("http://localhost:%d/users/create", port), user, User.class);     
    }
}
```

What can be a reason of this locking issue ?

**UPDATED:** - Added full stacktrace for org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException when I use @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException: null
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getCurrentTransaction(PersistenceManager.java:297)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getResource(PersistenceManager.java:249)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.currentKernelTransactionForReading(PersistenceManager.java:235)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.instance(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.createNode(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.DelegatingGraphDatabase.createNode(DelegatingGraphDatabase.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityStateHandler.createNode(EntityStateHandler.java:151)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityStateHandler.useOrCreateState(EntityStateHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.write(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.write(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:243)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:357)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:351)
    at com.example.domain.dao.user.UserDaoImpl.create(UserDaoImpl.java:32)
    at com.example.domain.service.user.UserServiceImpl.create(UserServiceImpl.java:38)
    at com.example.webservices.controller.users.UsersController.create(UsersController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:160)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try annotating your test with `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`.

Otherwise, Spring caches contexts across tests.

Comment: Added, now I have a following exception - org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException: null
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getCurrentTransaction(PersistenceManager.java:297)  Also, added @Transactional, but still doesn't work.

Comment: could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Sure, added full stacktrace into the question body

Comment: Clearly, a transaction hasn't been started. Are you sure you tried annotating UserServiceImpl's create method with @Transacitonal?

Comment: Yep, I have placed @Transactional annotation on each service/dao impl. It work perfectly on Neo4j server, and also work on separated tests with embedded Neo4j.. but fails on a set of test cases(on server Neo4j work good). Each second test case fails with a mentioned exception on embedded Neo4j.

Comment: super strange, could you create a simple project with a single test that reproduces the issue and put it on github? Or zip it up and send it by email? info at graphaware dot com. At this point, the only thing I can try doing is debugging though it...

Comment: Thanks Michal!  I have sent you the source.